# Table elements alignment for responsive page

Tags: css

This is how the page looks like-

[image]

Note that the image size is fixed here but the title is not fixed. In some case, the title takes more than one line. This destroys the complete view and it doesn't look nice. Please see below the generated html-

[image]

I have defined two `css` class *awards* and *award-list* for this table.

I wanted to know, what is the best approach to align the image horizontally, while keeping the title of various lengths? Please note that, I can't fix the shape (width and height) of text `div`, because the page is responsive. I am looking for some `css` hack here.

Comment: Post a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: @zer00ne: I am using `views` inside `Drupal 7` framework. Please let me know, if you need more info.

Comment: Can't work with a picture of code. Need code that is comprised of text, not pixels.

Comment: @zer00ne: The HTML is generated by the framework.